# Why is the Socket provided by ServerSocket using a different port?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Server:

```
int port = 7000
ServerSocket ss;
..
System.out.println("Listening on " + ss.getInetAddress() + ":"
   + ss.getLocalPort());

Socket s = ss.accept();
..
System.out.println("Accepted connection " + s.getInetAddress() + ":"
   + s.getPort());
```

Client:

```
Socket s;
..
System.out.println("Connected to " + s.getInetAddress() + ":"
   + s.getPort());
```

Server starts listening:

`Listening on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:7000`

Client connects:

`Connected to localhost/127.0.0.1:7000`

But the server says that the socket is connected on a different port?

`Accepted connection /127.0.0.1:54682`

Referencing:

[Java the difference of Socket and ServerSocket in using port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730392/java-the-difference-of-socket-and-serversocket-in-using-port)

> .. ServerSocket.accept() accepts a connection, and wraps the endpoint in
>   a Socket. The endpoint has the same local port number as the
>   ServerSocket, by definition as per RFC 793, and therefore so does the
>   wrapping Socket.

and

> .. each client connection will get a separate Socket to communicate on,
>   all communicating using the same server side TCP port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getPort()` returns the remote port of the socket (i.e. other side address) while `getLocalPort()` returns the local port that the socket is bound to.

If you ran `s.getLocalPort());` on server accepted socket, you would get `7000` too.

Comment: To confirm: getPort() on the receiving end is the outgoing ephemeral port from the client?

Comment: @Zhro : I would rather say on the server end. In general `getPort()` always returns the remote port, i.e. client computer port for the server and server listening port for the client.

Comment: @Zhro I would rather just say it returns the remote port, and not think about clients and servers at all. Once the connection is complete there are just local ends and peers.